# What are the names of the new syntactic entities added for variadic templates?

Tags: c++, terminology, c++11, variadic-templates

C++11 introduced [variadic templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template)

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... params) {
    cout << sizeof...(Args) << endl;
}
```

What are the names of `Args` and `params`? I know that one of them (at least?) is called a variadic template pack but which is it? And what is the other called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Partially quoting the FDIS, §14.5.3:

> <sup>1</sup> A *template parameter pack* is a template parameter that accepts zero or more template arguments.
>
> <sup>2</sup> A *function parameter pack* is a function parameter that accepts zero or more function arguments.
>
> <sup>3</sup> A *parameter pack* is either a template parameter pack or a function parameter pack.
>
> <sup>4</sup> A *pack expansion* consists of a *pattern* and an ellipsis, the instantiation of which produces zero or more instantiations of the pattern in a list.

So in your example,

- `typename... Args` is a *template parameter pack* (and consequently also a *parameter pack*)
- `Args... params` is a *function parameter pack* (and consequently also a *parameter pack*)
- `sizeof...(Args)` is a *pack expansion* wherein `Args` is the *pattern* (an identifier in this context).

Comment: And also, `typename... Args` is a *template parameter pack*, but it is not a *pack expansion*. In `template<typename ...Args> class A { template<Args... B> class C { }; template<template<Args D> class ...E> class F { }; };`, the `B` is a *template parameter pack*. The `Args ...B` is its declaration which is also a *pack expansion* of the pattern `Args B`, expanding into a *template-parameter-list*. `template<Args D> class ...E` is also a pack expansion of pattern `template<Args D> class E`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb could you post this comment as an answer? It's certainly detailed enough.

Comment: can you explain your fourth point i.e pattern thing , I mean how that pattern thing works? and in which part of c++ it works :)